# Can I leave my bag in the Uffizi Gallery?

Tags: luggage, italy, luggage-storage, florence

I have a large bag I don't want to walk around Florence with. Can I leave it in baggage deposit in Uffizi and come back for it in the evening after
I see the rest of the city?

I have tickets to Uffizi, so it could be cheaper than using the deposit at the railway station.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes you can!**

When entering the Uffizi after the security check you enter a small lobby. There is a cloakroom on the right before you enter the gallery on your left/straight in front of you. It is free of charge and you can leave backpacks, umbrellas and large bags.

[Link](http://www.uffizi.org/museum/services/)

Comment: Warning: the maximum size of a bag in the Uffizi gallery cloakroom is 50 x 40 x 40 cm! However they let me deposit my larger bag after some negotiation.